# Free application for cross-platform programming? iOS/Android/Mac/Windows/Linux

Tags: gratis, software-development, cross-platform

I would like to receive opinions from everyone that what programming applications supports cross platform. I had already know some of it for example Xamarin, it supports cross platform and uses the same code for iOS, Android, Mac and Windows.

The main problem is that it's too expensive for me. I am a personal and single programmer and I don't really want to pay a large amount for it.

Can anyone suggest me what programming applications or language do you prefer to allow cross platform applications (and even mobile apps) for free?

Comment: Do you need generated apps to be runnable on Linux too?

Comment: Yes, I would like to create apps that also run on linux. Basically all common operating systems.

Comment: Too broad. Way too broad.
Good questions should not be answerable with a list.
Everything from Java, to Python to C with the right libraries.

Answer (score 7):

I use [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) C++.

> Qt is a cross-platform application and UI framework for developers using C++ or QML, a CSS & JavaScript like language. Qt Creator is the supporting Qt IDE. Qt Cloud Services provides connected application backend features to Qt applications.

Advantages:

- It is licensed under GPL v3 and LGPL v2.1 for as long as your apps built with it are licensed under one of the two licenses.
- same code for multiple operating systems.
- powerful C++ classes (for example take a look at [QString](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QString.html)).
- the SDK includes a very good and complete IDE.
- very easy to create GUI apps.
- you can theme your apps with CSS-like styles (my favourite).
- mobile support for Android and BlackBerry.

Disadvantages:

- if you want to distribute your apps you must include Qt libraries which even for a simple app take up to 10-20 MB depending on what libs are used, what version of Qt are you using.
- if you want to make closed-source apps you must use Qt under commercial license from [Digia](http://qt.digia.com/).
- no 64 bit with MinGW on Windows (unless you build Qt from source). Must use Microsoft's compiler for 64 bit apps.

Here is screenshot of Qt Creator IDE:

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks for the opinion! I am now downloading QT Creator. It seems great and really cross-platform. Thanks!

Comment: @user294928 VLC, SMPlayer, the whole KDE desktop environment for Linux are some examples of apps built with Qt. See more at http://qt-apps.org

Comment: Correction: Qt can be used for closed source apps, look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945612/qt-lgpl-licencing-for-a-free-application-with-closed-source. For MinGW 64-bit builds of the SDK(QtCreator and libraries) look here http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/external-binary-packages/Qt-Builds/

Comment: I'll point out as a Mac user (and Qt developer) that it's great. Interface snobs can definitely tell it's not perfect, but Qt's *much* better than anything else I've used at getting details right. I haven't tried mobile development, but I know it's possible.